# inputting data with pointers in class in c++

Tags: c++, objective-c, pointers

i wanted to write a code(with using pointers) to get two sides of a rectangular and calculate the perimeter and area of it but it's not working
here goes the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
class PAndArea{
private:
    int x, y;
    void getxy(int *,int *);
    int area(int *, int *);
    int perimeter(int *, int *);
public:
    void showperimeterandarea(int *, int *);
};
void PAndArea::showperimeterandarea(int *w, int *e)
{
    getxy(*w, *e);
    cout << "area:"<<area(*w, *e)<< "<br>";
    cout << "perimeter:" << perimeter(*w, *e);
}
void PAndArea::getxy(int *x, int*y)
{
    cout << "enter two numbers:";
    cin >> *x >> *y;
}
int PAndArea::area(int *x,int *y)
{
    return (*x * *y);
}
int PAndArea::perimeter(int *x, int *y)
{
    return((*x * 2) + (*y * 2));
}

int main(){
    int x, y;
    PAndArea i;
    i.showperimeterandarea(&x, &y);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `but it's not working`  Tell us what you mean by "it's not working".  It doesn't compile, it crashes, ...?

Comment: Including the actual compiler error messages in your question is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing int's to a function that takes int pointers.

```
int area(int *, int *);
//...
area(*w, *e);
```

w and e are int*.  When you dereference them as you're doing in the call, a *w and *e are ints (not pointers).

Either change the area function to take int's, or pass pointers to area.

```
    int area(int *, int *);
    //...
    area(w, e);

    // or

    int area(int, int);
    //...
    area(*w, *e);
```

You also make the same error in other calls.  For example:

```
void PAndArea::showperimeterandarea(int *w, int *e)
{
   // getxy(*w, *e);  // you are passing int's here, not pointers.  This is wrong
   getxy(w, e);  // correction
```

Comment: i can't totally understand you
you mean i have to change area(*w,*e) to area(w,e)?

Comment: You need to understand the compiler error that you received instead of just reading my answer.  Once you understand what that error is telling you, then you will understand the fix you need to make.

Comment: it says
Eerror C2664: 'void PAndArea::getxy(int *,int *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int *'

what part of it do i have to change?

Comment: `cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int *'`  Do you understand what that error means?  Now look at the answer I gave you (like I said, the error not only occurs with the call to area() but other functions as well).  Again, you are passing int's when the function takes int*.  So the fix is simple - stop passing int's.

Comment: yes!!!
you mean this:

 getxy(w, e);
 cout << "area:" << area(w, e) << "<br>";
 cout << "perimeter:" << perimeter(w, e);

thanks a lot man